# featuretools: got an error "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ww'"

Tags: featuretools

when i try to use featuretools[spark] on pyspark dataframe
my code are bellow:

```
import featuretools as ft
import pyspark.pandas as ps
from woodwork.logical_types import Double, Integer

ps.set_option("compute.default_index_type", "distributed")

id = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
values = [12, -35, 14, 103, -51]

spark_df = ps.DataFrame({"id": id, "values": values})

es = ft.EntitySet(id="spark_es")
es = es.add_dataframe(
    dataframe_name="spark_input_df",
    dataframe=spark_df,
    index="id",
    logical_types={"id": Integer, "values": Double},
)

es
```

bug got an error
"AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ww'"

anyone can help me ?

I just run the official code post on "https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/guides/using_spark_entitysets.html"

Comment: The code you posted runs fine for me. I suspect the error might be a result of the versions of libraries you have installed or something else specific to your installation. What versions of Featuretools, Woodwork and pyspark do you have installed in your environment? What operating system are you running?

Answer (score 0):

This code you provided works for me.

The lib versions:

1. Featuretools: 1.21.0
2. Pyspark: 3.3.0.dev0

Answer (score -2):

Import pyspark.pandas as ps first